# R: Creating and saving a table to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

This is such a simple sounding problem, and yet I can't find a solution to my problem. I have created a table from a previous data.frame in order to organize my data differently (see below)

Section of dataframe1 below

```
 Score   Pred
 0.966   Noise
 0.95    Noise
 0.964   Noise
 0.924   Call
 0.838   Noise
 0.982   Call
 0.934   Noise
```

Organizing my data into a table using the following:

```
dataframe1_sorted <- with(dataframe1, table(Score, Pred))
```

This creates a table with the following: I want to have a count of how many "Call"s and how many "Noise"s there are in each Score category.

```
Score    Pred Call Noise
0           0  402     0
0.002       0  207     0
0.004       0  120     0
0.006       0   83     0
0.008       0   59     0
0.01        0   48     0
```

Now, when I try to save this table using **df<-data.frame(dataframe1)**, it changes the columns, and I get headings *"Score, Pred, Freq"*. I want to save the table to dataframe exactly as it is.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unclassing the table:

```
df<-data.frame(unclass(dataframe1))
```

I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: How strange, as I've tried unclassing my table before and I ended up with nonsense. It works this time though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem before and done this:

```
tab <- with(dat, table(Score, Pred))
class(tab) <- 'matrix'
data.frame(tab)
```

**EDIT:** Using `'array'` instead of `'matrix'` also works, and should extend to higher-dimensional tables.

Comment: This works fine, thank you! :) Just so I understand, you classified the table as a 'matrix' first, and then saved it as a data.frame?

Comment: @Mengll Yep. Initially, I had tried `as.matrix`, but that does not get rid of the `table` class. `unclass`ing it (as @mrip proposed) also yields a matrix; check `class(unclass(tab))`

Answer (score 1):

One alternative outside of base R would be to use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package.  The output of this is a data.frame, so you don't have to resave it.  One thing I like about this is that you get names for each of your columns.

```
require(reshape2)
(df = dcast(dataframe1, Score ~ Pred, fun.aggregate = length) )
```

Comment: This is great! I couldn't find code that would have a data.frame output so I went in a round-about way to get there. I'll check out the reshape package.